# How do I "catch" multiple forms with different form ids with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

Multiple forms are placed on a single page and are submitted via jquery. The code that submits the form is simple:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
});
```

The issue I am having is having a select group of forms run with this code. I have tried the following with success:

```
$("#form1,#form2,#form3").submit(function() {
});
```

However, is it possible select multiple forms with a single id/identifier?

Additionally, when using multiple ids to select form1, form2, and form3, what data is submitted? I have a hidden field located in form1 but it seems as if that data is sent when form2 is submitted. How can I correct this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're kind of misunderstanding how ID's work. ID's are unique to the entire page, you can't have multiple elements, let alone specifically multiple form elements, with the same ID. What is it you are trying to do ?

Comment: As Khez may be alluding to, you're probably looking to instead (or additionally) assign a class to these elements and then use that class.

Comment: I realize that ids are unique (hence the multiple ids in the second bit of code). I am asking for a workaround or other methods of accomplishing this.

Comment: Can a class be added to form and it work with the jQuery? I've tried this without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form id="form1" class="formClass"></form>
<form id="form2" class="formClass"></form>
<form id="form3" class="formClass"></form>
<form id="form4" class="formClass"></form>


$(".formClass").submit();
```

Comment: it should be $(".formClass").submit()

Comment: @Ian Jasper Bardoquillo When any one of the forms is submitted, how can I collect the data in javascript from the form submitted and not any others?

Comment: @tundoopani: Hi, I posted an answer to your question. Please have a check on it, I do hope it helps you :)

Answer (score 1):

That first piece of code is a JavaScript event that is called on submit. It doesn't actually submit the form (omitting the function will, however).

You can select multiple forms using any valid jQuery selector. The easiest method will be to give them a class you can refer to easily.

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick test [in a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JimmySawczuk/s2mky/). The script these forms point to is:

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);

error_log(var_export($_POST, true));
```

The error log output was:

```
[error] [client 192.168.9.1] array (\n  'field1' => '1',\n), referer: http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/
```

I take this to mean that a) only one form submitted, and b) it was the first form in the DOM. Someone correct me if part of my methodology is wrong.

Essentially, what this will mean is that you'll want to interrupt any `submit` events and combine all of the form data into one set of parameters before submitting.

Answer (score 0):

Please [check here in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xJMQh/1/). I hope it helps or at least will give you an idea. :)

Comment: I see what the code does, but how can I have only one form submit at a time?