# jquery catch all function on Submit form

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am having trouble creating a "Grab All" function for submitting form data. I have multiple forms that I want to reuse the same jQuery.

My current function is this:

```
$('.submit-grabber').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    $.post('grabber.php', data, function(data) {
        communicatorDisplay(data);
    }); 
});
```

My HTML is this:

```
<form id="product" class="submit-grabber">
    // Form elements go here
</form>

<form id="category" class="submit-grabber">
    // Form Elements go here
</form>
```

Before I created a "Catch All", I used a function for everyone of the forms, by id:

```
$('#product').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $('#product').serialize();
    $.post('grabber.php', data, function(data) {
        communicatorDisplay(data);
    }); 
});
```

And that worked, however, switching to a "Catch All", it seems to cancel the `e.preventDefault()` element and it will not submit, what am I doing wrong?

I've also consulted [How do I "catch" multiple forms with different form ids with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671151/how-do-i-catch-multiple-forms-with-different-form-ids-with-jquery) but that didn't seem to offer any explanation

Comment: This works ok, My mistake. Left some open code somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

never mind all, this works fine. I had accidentally left some open code & brackets somewhere on the page.